# install .EXE on server

Tags: node.js

I have an EXE file (wrote by C++) which receive an input file (.txt) and do process then return results in a TXT file. Now I want to write an API by NodeJS and I need to have access to this EXE file on server, open it, give it a specific input file and then send the result as response. Is it possible? and if yes how ? I read something about TSplus or remote app, but I don't think these could be useful.

I tried to find ways to install a program on the server and then be able to control that program with NodeJS.

Comment: Provided your server runs Windows and the application is not using a GUI: Look into the `child_process` core module.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.